# Laravel - How to disable CSRF only for duo security

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

We are using duo security for two factor authentication. So after login in laravel, I am redirecting the user to duo page for second level of authentication. After successfully completing 2FA, user gets page expired because of CSRF issue.
I know specific routes can be exempted from CSRF using `VerifyCsrfToken.php` file. But in my case the 2FA form is external and I am loading it using an iframe. I have modified `login()` method of `vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php` for redirecting the user to duo iframe for 2nd level authentication.
Below is the `form` tag from duo iframe:

```
<form action="/frame/prompt" method="post" id="login-form" class="inline login-form">
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="ZDFhNmNlMWE0NTExNDg0NThlMTA1Y2U2ODhjYzA3NjM=|14.98.2.146|1605100624|c6849b048c469b7ab3ec46ce9bd5c2483f18e7e1">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="/frame/prompt">
<input type="hidden" name="should_retry_u2f_timeouts" value="False">

<input type="hidden" id="has_phone_that_requires_compliance_text" name="has_phone_that_requires_compliance_text" value="False">

<fieldset class="device-selector hidden">
<h1 class="cramped-frame-view">
Device:
</h1>
<div class="device-select-wrapper">
<select name="device" aria-label="Device" tabindex="2">
<option value="phone1">Android (+XX XXXXX X6607)</option>
</select>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div id="auth_methods">
<fieldset data-device-index="phone1" class="">
<h2 class="medium-or-larger auth-method-header">
Choose an authentication method
</h2>
<div class="row-label push-label">
<input type="hidden" name="factor" value="Duo Push">
<span class="label factor-label">
<i class="icon-smartphone-check"></i>
Duo Push
</span>
<button type="submit" class="positive auth-button" tabindex="2"><!-- -->Send Me a Push </button>
</div>
<div class="passcode-label row-label">
<input type="hidden" name="factor" value="Passcode">
<span class="label factor-label">
<i class="icon-smartphone-ellipsis" alt="" role="presentation"></i>
Passcode
</span>
<div class="passcode-input-wrapper">
<input type="text" name="passcode" autocomplete="off" data-index="phone1" class="hidden passcode-input" placeholder="ex. 867539" aria-label="passcode" tabindex="2">
<div class="next-passcode-msg" role="alert" aria-live="polite"></div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="positive auth-button" tabindex="2" id="passcode"><!-- -->Enter a Passcode </button>
<input name="phone-smsable" type="hidden" value="True">
<input name="mobile-otpable" type="hidden" value="True">
<input name="next-passcode" type="hidden" value="None">
</div>
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="has-token" value="false">
</div>
<div>
</div>
</form>
```

Now what should I keep inside `protected $except = []` array in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

add like that in in your `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` file.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/frame/prompt'
    ];
}
```